# Аналог функции Swap

Tags: c#, delphi

Есть ли в С# аналог функции Delphi Swap() ?
Верно ли я понимаю, что функция swap меняет местами 2 байта ?

Comment: Вы сначала укажите, что именно делает функция Delphi Swap.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow [Swap](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Swap.html): _In Delphi code, Swap exchanges the high-order bytes with the low-order bytes of the argument. X is an expression of type SmallInt, as a 16-bit value, or Word. This is provided for backward compatibility only._

Comment: Use help, Luke: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Swap . Да, меняет местами старший и младший байт

Comment: На [английской версии есть подобный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236193/how-to-duplicate-delphis-swap-function-in-c-sharp), там привели пример, как аналог написать, вроде нет такой функции в C#

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin Спасибо, выручил !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В комментариях подсказали, где подсмотреть готовое решение:

Для данных типа ushort:

```
private ushort Swap(ushort number)
    {
        var hi = (byte)(number >> 8);
        var lo = (byte)(number & 0xff);
        return (ushort)((lo << 8) | hi);
    }
```

Для данных типа Int:

```
int SwapInt(int number)
    {
        var hi = (byte)(number >> 24);
        var lo = (byte)(number & 0xff);
        return ((number & 0xffff00) | (lo << 24) | hi);
    }
```

Comment: Вы привели только часть решения, потому как `Swap` из Delphi работает с `Integer`. Рекомендую дополнить ответ, что бы был **полный** аналог этой функции.